# How to use foreach for the textboxes in a panel

Tags: c#, textbox

I have 9 textboxes created in design time. By clicking a listbox (inglist created in design time) i select an item, IfThisExist(CmpStr) function verify if i've allready choosed this one. When I debug the value of CmpStr is passed to txt.Text but it's not displayed in on screen.

```
string CmpString;
bool SelectedExist;
CmpSt r = Convert.ToString(inglist.Items[inglist.SelectedIndex]);
SelectedExist = IfThisExist(CmpStr);

if (inglist.SelectedIndex > -1 && rows > 0 && SelectedExist == false)
{
  foreach (Control txt in mypanel.Controls)
  {
    if (txt is TextBox && txt.Text == "" )
    {
      txt.Text = CmpStr;
      break;
    }
    else if (txt is TextBox && txt.Text == CmpStr)
        break;
  }
```

If I do same thing with the method below it works.

```
//for (int j = 0; j < rows; ++j)
//{
//   switch (j + 1)
//{
//  case 1:
//    if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox1.Text!= CmpStr) 
//  {
//    textBox1.Text = CmpStr;
//  passed = true;
//   }
//  break;
```

.....

What can be the reason ?

Comment: Your below method is WAY different from your current code. Also you show only a part of you method, which does not help. 
You switch statement below is not present above, so you logic is not the same. Also, I don't understand clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Joel Sorry for the second method because it's too long. But in short explanation the rest is the same as case 1. In each case it compares another textbox such textbox2.text, textbox3.text... with CmpStr. How ever the second method works very well but it's too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry disturbing, foreach loop begins from the greater tabindex to the lower. As I was hiding the textboxes unused, this is the  greater tabindex textboxes which is receiving the value of CmpStr.

```
if (inglist.SelectedIndex > -1 && rows > 0 && SelectedExist == false)
{
            
    foreach (Control txt in mypanel.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(c => c.TabIndex))
    {
        if (txt is TextBox && txt.Text == "")
        {
            txt.Text = CmpStr;
            break;
        }
        else if (txt is TextBox && txt.Text == CmpStr)
            break;
    }
}
```

And that works well.

Comment: Glad you have solved your problem! You should use `OfType<TextBox>` instead of `Cast<TextBox>` because if you have more controls (non-textbox) you will get an `InvalidCastException`. See my update :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your question can be improved, but IF I understood it right, you want to iterate trough your textoxes.

**EDIT (to adapt to below comment):**

<s>Also, some code is missing, as I don't know about your `switch` stantement, your case `(j+1)`, I don't know the context of the code.</s>

Ignoring your switch statemente, I'd suggest you code to look something like this:

```
string CmpString;
Boolean SelectedExist;
CmpStr=Convert.ToString(inglist.Items[inglist.SelectedIndex]);
SelectedExist = IfThisExist(CmpStr);

if (inglist.SelectedIndex > -1 && rows > 0 && SelectedExist == false)
{
    var sortedTextboxes = mypanel.Controls
        .OfType<TextBox>() // get all textboxes controls
        .OrderBy(ctrl => ctrl.TabIndex); // order by TabIndex

    foreach (TextBox txt in sortedTextboxes)
    {
        // No need to cast :)

        if(txt.Text == "") 
        {  
            tBox.Text = CmpStr;
            break;
        }

        if(txt.Text == CmpStr) { break; }
    }
}
```

Notice the `OfType<TextBox>` method, which returns only textboxes.

<s>However, this code is not of much help without modification, because text will only be set to textbox if it is empty.</s>
Once again, adapt the code to fit your needs.

Comment: the reason of my bug is the loop of foreach. It works from the higher tabindex to the lower, so the methode that I write was working. But as my program hides the unused textboxes and as the CmpStr is assigned from the last to the first textbox, I was not seeing in the display. I resolved by useing foreach in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control txt in mypanel.Controls) {
    if (txt is TextBox) {
        if ((txt as TextBox).Text == "") {
            (txt as TextBox).Text = CmpStr;
            break;
        } else if ((txt as TextBox).Text == CmpStr) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Casting 5 times from control to textbox? Why not just cast first txt as TextBox and then check if it is null, much more efficient...

Comment: Sorry disturbing, foreach loop begins from the greater tabindex to the lower. As I was hiding the textboxes unused, this is the  greater tabindex textboxes which is receiving the value of CmpStr.

Comment: Also, your else code will NEVER get executed! Because your if will be always false (if it wasn't, code would never hit your else, anyway).